# convert DateTime to another time zone

Tags: php, date, time

I have a time in `4:40 pm et`, how to convert it in `H:i:s`, I have used this :

```
date ('H:i:s' ,strtotime('4:40 pm et'));
```

Comment: Have you searched for it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use see [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) and [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php 
$old =  date ('H:i:s' ,strtotime('4:40 pm et'));
$date = new DateTime($old);
$newdate = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow')); // +0
print_r($newdate);
```

Comment: if i add date also like '2015-05-25 4:40 pm et' ???

Comment: Yes you can ! Have a try :)

Comment: I have tried but it gives me time from 1970-01-01

Comment: When i use this `2015-05-25 4:40 pm et`  i can see this `DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-05-25 03:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Moscow )` in the output